# how can i make space between two fixed navbar with the container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i don't know if the title of my question is related to my problem because i couldn't get  better than this sentence ;

i have problem with this code  , i have two fixed navbar one in the top and the other in the left and the real problem is like this image and on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stsx60kr/1/)

[image: problem]

the problem is the top nav is above the other nav and i need the top one to be  next the left nav like this

[image: fix]

the real problem also when i'm using container the other div come above the left side like this photo

[image]

how can i fix this problem ? ?

my code is

```
<body style="background-color:#F2F2F2">
<div style="position: relative; z-index: 3;">
 <div class="navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color:#3e474f;height:643px;width:69px;z-index: 2;">
        <ul>

        <li><a  class="fa fa-th-large fa-2x"href="#"></a></li>   <li><a  class="fa fa-th-large fa-2x"href="#"></a></li>   <li><a  class="fa fa-th-large fa-2x"href="#"></a></li>   <li><a  class="fa fa-th-large fa-2x"href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>

        <nav style="z-index: 1"class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header navbar-left">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="myNavbar">

              <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>

            </div>
ass="container">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-6 ">
 <div class="panel-group ">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Panel with panel-default class</div>
      <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">

 <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Panel with panel-default class</div>
      <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
    </div>
 </div>


</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
 <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Panel with panel-default class</div>
      <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="col-sm-6">
 <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Panel with panel-default class</div>
      <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>



</div>
</div>
 <!--------> 

</body>
```

and on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stsx60kr/1/)

Comment: On a side note, Wrap your `row` inside a container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, try add you your `.navbar` and `.row` - `margin-left` value.

```
.navbar, .row {
    margin-left: 69px;
}
```

Comment: @badr glad to help you!

Comment: Should also take @ManojKumar's advice and wrap the rows in a container as this will stop horizontal scrolling (rows set a negative margin).

Answer (score 3):

Alesha's answer is correct, but I noticed it leaves the panel contents hidden, to fix it add this code instead.

```
.row{
   padding-top:50px;
   padding-left:75px;
}

.navbar-brand{
   padding-left: 75px;
}
```